# DialogFlow - How can I give the same response from different intents?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to give the same response from different intents, using or not using a context.

For instance, my bot can ask:

> I can give you the duration of these topics: grades / masters

Let's suppose the user says 'grades'. The bot should answer: "4 years".
This particular intent needs a context or the bot will reply with all information he can give about that topic.

Now let's suppose the user says 'duration of a grade' in any context. The bot should give the same response.

So what can I do to avoid duplicating intents? (one contextualized, and another one not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Intents represent what the user is saying - not how you're responding.

The easiest way to do this is to use a webhook for fulfillment. Then set the Intent Handler for both to the same function.

You could also set the "action name" for the two Intents to the same value and check for this name in your fulfillment. (Libraries such as [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) make this aspect easier.)

There is no easy way to do this without fulfillment.